# How can I take a look at my framebuffers?

Tags: debugging, opengl, framebuffer

As the title says, how can I verify if my framebuffers got rendered properly?

Is the best way to use glReadPixels and save the content to an image? If so, is there a simple open source library for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [gDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com/free_license.php), it's best for the task. Allows to see buffers, textures, calls, states and lots of other useful information.